# US Universities and colleges with city/town state?

Tags: data-request, usa, city

Is there any database or list that has the major US universities and colleges with the city/town, state they are located in?

Answer (score 4):

[Database of Accredited Postsecondary Institutions and Programs](http://ope.ed.gov/accreditation/GetDownLoadFile.aspx) by the Department of Education has this data for download in CSV and XLSX.